# clarity of -1L < 1U and -1L > 1UL

Tags: c

I have been reading the book **The C Programming Language by K&R** and came across this.

---

Conversion rules are more complicated when unsigned operands are involved. The problem
is that comparisons between signed and unsigned values are machine-dependent, because
they depend on the sizes of the various integer types. For example, suppose that int is 16 bits and long is 32 bits. Then **-1L < 1U**, because 1U, which is an unsigned int, is promoted to a signed long. But **-1L > 1UL** because -1L is promoted to unsigned long and thus appears
to be a large positive number.

---

From my beginning of C, i have little difficult regarding this Unsigned and Signed values. Can any one Explain how an unsigned value converted to signed value and viceversa with an explample.

Comment: +1 An authoritative link with detailed explanation is in order! I don't have one. Although K&R text makes perfect sense to me, I see how it confuses beginners.

Comment: If you are looking for an explanation of signed vs. unsigned values, than you can probably find it in absolutely any C introduction. I’m not really sure what is the question here…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have touched the surface of *usual arithmetic conversions* with *integral promotions* (newer standards use term of *integer promotions* there).

### What are these *usual arithmetic conversions* ?

In general when you have expression, that involves arithmetic or logical operator and operands don't match, then they need to be unified (as we say promoted) into common form. In **C90** rules between integer operands (I am skipping intentionally rules for types "lower" that `int` here for simplicity) are in following gradation (note that there is no `long long int` type in C90):

`int` → `unsigned int` → `long int` → `unsigned long int`

However, there is one exception between `unsigned int` and `long int`. If these have the same size (in bits), then both operands of such types are promoted to common type `unsigned long int`. In any other case common type is that, which is on right side (e.g. when you have `int` and `unsigned int` operands, then first one is promoted to `unsigned int`). If both operands have the same type, then no promotion is made for types listed above.

### How does this relate to `-1L < 1U` and `-1L > 1UL` ?

In your case it's assumed that `sizeof(int) == 16` and `sizeof(long) = 32`, so for:

- `-1L < 1U` second operand is promoted to `long int`
- `-1L > 1UL` first operand is promoted to `unsigned long`

In former example value of expression is `1` as `-1L < 1L`. In latter case `-1L` is promoted to unsigned type by repeatedly adding or substracting `n+1`, when `n` is the largest value of type `unsigned long` (in your case `n+1 == 2^32`), which yields into large number (i.e. `2^32-1`), thus value of whole expression is `1` (of type `int`) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hum... there is a longer (detailed) answer, and a shorter (approximate) answer...

---

#### ...starting with the longer answer:

The standard (C99, 6.3.1) specifies an *integer conversion rank*, and where two integer operands have different *rank*, one will be converted up.  The *rank* is related to the size of the integer; larger sizes have greater rank than smaller sizes.  Where the sizes are the same there may be differences in rank -- but that's not important just now.  However, a signed integer and an unsigned integer of the same size have the same *rank*.

It's worth remembering that signed `int` and `unsigned int` have the same size, by definition.  They are examples of what the standard calls *corresponding* integer types (C99, 6.2.5).  Each signed integer type has a corresponding unsigned one, and vice versa -- except for `_Bool` which doesn't have a sign (and, FWIW, has the lowest *rank*).  As above, *corresponding* signed and unsigned types have the same *rank*.

C is very fond of `int` and `unsigned int`.  It will promote integers of lesser *rank* to `int` (or to `unsigned int`, if the promoted integer is unsigned and the same size as `int`).  This is called *integer promotion* (which is a subset of all the possible *conversions*).  For many operators, C will perform *integer promotion* on both operands before doing anything else.  It will also perform *integer promotion* on arguments for things like `printf()`.

Now we get to what are known as the *usual arithmetic conversions* (C99, 6.3.1.8), which for two integer operands are:

1. both arguments are *promoted* as required, so will be at least `int` or `unsigned int`
2. if they are now **not** the same type (type, not *rank*):

   - if both types are signed, or both types are unsigned, the lower *rank* is converted to the higher.

     This is straightforward, and there is clearly no loss of signed-ness.

   ...otherwise, for different types, of different signed-ness, size matters:

   - if the signed operand has the greater size (and hence *rank*), the unsigned operand is converted to the type of the signed one.

     This is also straightforward, the unsigned value can be represented, without loss, in the signed type.
   - if the unsigned operand has the greater size (and hence *rank*), the signed operand is converted to the type of the unsigned one.

     So, for (say) `unsigned long long` and `int` (which one assumes are different sizes), the `int` is converted up, by adding `ULLONG_MAX + 1` to it.

     This is not so straightforward, the signed-ness is lost.

   ...otherwise, for different types, of different signed-ness, of the same size, the result will be two unsigned operands of their current size.  The *rank* kicks in to decide what type the operands will be:

   - if the operands have the same *rank*, then the signed one is converted to the unsigned operand's type.

     This is what happens when you have `int` and `unsigned int` operands, the `int` is converted (by adding `UINT_MAX + 1` to it).
   - if the unsigned operand has the greater *rank*, then the signed operand is converted to the unsigned operand's type (as above).
   - otherwise, the signed operand has the greater *rank*, and both operands are converted to the unsigned type corresponding to the signed operand's type (ie to the unsigned type with the greater *rank*).

This all looks terrifyingly complicated :-(  But, keep in mind that the size of an integer is the major component of its *rank* -- what makes it look complicated dealing with integers of the same size, but different signedness and type.

(For the picky: I have glossed over the wrinkle in the standard which allows for integer representations to include "padding" bits -- which is deeply exotic -- so, for size read width, where required.)

---

#### ...but the essence of it is, in short:

After promotion to `int` or `unsigned int`:

1. if the operands have different sizes, the smaller is converted up, and if larger is unsigned but the smaller is not, the smaller loses its signed-ness.
2. if the operands have the same size, but different signed-ness, the signed one is converted to unsigned, losing signed-ness.

The conversion to unsigned (the loss of signed-ness) requires the addition of MAX+1, where MAX is the maximum value of the unsigned type being converted to.

Hence: `-1L > 0UL`... indeed `-1L == ULONG_MAX`.